# Can number + 部 mean the number of copies?

Tags: counters

For an upcoming conference, I'm supposed to bring copies of my own materials. One sentence contains a phrase that I'm a little unsure how to understand. First the Japanese sentence in its entirety:

> 参加者に配付する資料がありましたら,当日90部をご持参願います。

I believe I understand the conditional part and most of the rest. I understand it to say "if you have any materials to distribute to the participants, please bring then on the day [of the conference]."

Where I'm confused is the 90部.

My first instinct was to understand 90部 the name of an office or room at that university. But nothing else is named in that way in the document.

OR

My second guess is that it is saying I should bring 90 copies of the materials.

What does it mean in this context?

Comment: entry number 5: http://tangorin.com/general/%E9%83%A8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the definition for 部 in 数え方の辞典:

> ② 書籍やひとまとまりの文書を数えます。
>
> a. 書物や印刷物などの、複製した数を数えます。
>
> 「１００万部のベストセラー小説」
>   　　　「コピーを２０部作成する」
>
> b. 数冊の書籍を一括して数えるのに用います。
>
> 「１部５冊」

So yes, 部 is a counter for copies of printed materials, as in sense 2a.  This counter isn't limited to just newspapers and magazines like WWWJDIC appears to suggest, and it doesn't refer to a room number.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, 部 is a counter for copies of a newspapers, etc. and it applies to a broader range of printed materials as well.

[WWWJDIC](http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jwb/cgi-bin/wwwjdic.cgi) gives one of the meanings as "(5) counter for copies of a newspaper or magazine." It also gives 一部 as a broader meaning "one copy (e.g. of a document)."